# Largest mountain range

Tags: mountains, orogeny

The major mountain chains of Earth are found near:
Convergent (subduction) and convergent (collisional) boundaries or transform boundaries?[image]

it should be both subduction and collisional right?

Comment: Your map has the answer written on it. Do a bit of thought before you post a question here.

Comment: It should be both collision and subduction because Andes and Himalayas cover most of the mountains.

Comment: How do you define "large" or "major"? Both tectonic settings have large and major mountain ranges.

Comment: This has the feel of a homework question. In case it is, please see the policy on homework questions here: http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/316/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-earth-science-stack-exchange/317#317